# Adding Mobile Pages to a Website

Tags: mobile, seo

Although I understand the merits of responsive design, it would be far too complicated to convert my entire site to that method of handling mobile devices. So what I am working towards is a user-agent check at the beginning of each page that then picks out a PHP include that contains the bulk of the content. There is then one include for desktop and one for mobile. The code snippet at the beginning of each page looks something like this:

```
<?php
include("../includes/UAsniffer.php");
if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
include("../includes/xyz_mobile.php");
}else{
include("../includes/xyz.php");
}
?>
```

The content of the two version will be very similar with mostly CSS differences ada few things missing from the mobile version for simplicity.

The advantage from an SEO point-of-view (I think) is that the same URL is displayed regardless of device. However, will search engines object to seeing something slightly different? Or will they even notice?

Answer (score 0):

Main Search Engines **will detect** that you serve mobile version for clients with mobile user-agents.